# How to convert Big Endian and how to flip the highest bit?

Tags: delphi

I am using a TStream to read binary data (thanks to this post: [How to use a TFileStream to read 2D matrices into dynamic array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878180/how-to-use-a-tfilestream-to-read-2d-matrices-into-dynamic-array)).

My next problem is that the data is Big Endian. From my reading, the  Swap() method is seemingly deprecated.  How would I swap the types below?

```
 16-bit two's complement binary integer
 32-bit two's complement binary integer
 64-bit two's complement binary integer
 IEEE single precision floating-point - Are IEEE affected by Big Endian?
```

And, finally, since the data is unsigned, the creators of this dataset have stored the unsigned values as signed integers (excluding the IEEE).  They instruct that one need only add an offset (2^15, 2^31, and 2^63) to recover the unsigned data.  But, they note that flipping the most significant bit is the fastest way to do that.  How does one efficiently flip the most significant bit of a 16, 32, or 64-bit integer?

So, if the data on disk (16-bit) is "85 FB" - the desired result after reading the data and swapping and bit flipping would be 1531.

Is there a way to accomplish the swapping and bit flipping with generics so it fits into the generic answer at the link above?

Yes, kids, THIS is how scientific astronomical data is stored by NASA, ESO, and all professional astronomers. This FITS standard is considered by some to be one of the most successful standards ever created in its proliferation and flexibility!

Comment: ... What? How did you get 1531 from that and not 7b85?

Comment: Yeah, I get 7B 85 too, which in decimal is 31621.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not tested:

```
function Flip16(const Value: Word): Word; inline;
begin
  Result:= Value xor $8000;
end;

function Flip32(const Value: LongWord): LongWord; inline;
begin
  Result:= Value xor $80000000;
end;

function Flip64(const Value: UInt64): UInt64; inline;
begin
  Result:= Value xor $8000000000000000;
end;

function SwapBytes(Value: LongWord): Single;
type
  Bytes = packed array[0..3] of Byte;

begin
  Bytes(Result)[0]:= Bytes(Value)[3];
  Bytes(Result)[1]:= Bytes(Value)[2];
  Bytes(Result)[2]:= Bytes(Value)[1];
  Bytes(Result)[3]:= Bytes(Value)[0];
end;
```

---

**Updated**: Well if you about to optimize :)

```
function SwapBytes(Value: LongWord): Single; register; 
asm
  BSWAP  EAX
end;
```

---

**Updated once more**:

A common practice in SO is one question per one post - it generally results in better answers.

1) Are IEEE affected by Big Endian?

Yes, floating-point values can be Big Endians, but it does not mean that your floating-point values are Big Endians - check your documentation.

2) flipping a most significant bit - the answer is already given, but since you probably have Big Endians you may need just to flip a most significant bit in a least significant byte, i.e. just xor $80;

3) converting big endian to little endian;

for 16-bit values use Swap function - it is hard to understand why delphi help says that the function is for backward compatibility only; it is also possible to use XCHG asm instruction as Remko noticed;

for 32-bit values your can use my code or code in Marco's comment;

for 64-bit values you can use a modification of Marco's code like this:

```
function Swap64(Value: UInt64): UInt64;
begin
  Result:= Swap32(LongWord(Value));
  Result:= (Result shl 32) or Swap32(LongWord(Value shr 32));
end;
```

4) Is it possible to use generics here?

I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: swap(word(value)) shl 16 + swap(word(value shr 16));

Comment: bswap eax swaps DWORD, to swap WORD use xchg al, ah

Comment: @user246408 - Who is 'swap32'? Is it defined in Delphi?

Comment: There is other ABI in 64-bit programs. So, `BSWAP  EAX` not working on x86_64. As far as I disasemble, in x86_64 first parameter is passed via ECX, and return parameter passed via EAX. So, you may use `BSWAP ECX` and `MOV EAX, ECX`, or you may use Value in asm: `bswap value` and `mov eax, Value`

Comment: @chabapok so, `bswap value` and `mov eax, Value` will work on 64bit apps to ?

Comment: @marus-gradinaru  Yes, I think it's better to use `bswap value`, becasue it's works on x86 and on x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know too much about byte swapping, but flipping a single bit is easy.  XOR your value with a mask whose binary representation is all 0s, except for a 1 for the bit you want to flip.  If you want the most significant bit, in hex that works out to `$80` for a single byte, `$8000` for a word and, you guessed it, `$80000000` for a double word.

Comment: And for 64-bit unsigned? : -)

Comment: Add another 8 zeros on the end of the 32-bit version. :P

Comment: Hmm, yes, seems that unsigned hex values are accepted. I'll test tonight if the arithmetic works. (FPC has an unsigned 64-bit type,QWORD delphi not)

Comment: @Marco: You've never heard of UInt64?

Comment: No. And neither did the help. But fairly old compilers seem to accept it. The only help I find (I'm behind old systems and only have D2006 here) is that it is an IDL type.