# Moving C# function to Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, type-conversion

I have the next function in C# and I need convert to Delphi. C# has BitConverter to do it easy but I dont know how to do in Delphi.

```
/// Reads a 4-byte floating point value from the current stream 
public override float ReadSingle(float sg)
{
    byte[] temp = BitConverter.GetBytes( sg );
    Array.Reverse(temp);
    float returnVal = BitConverter.ToSingle(temp, 0);
    return returnVal;
}
```

I have done:

```
procedure ReverseBytes(Source, Dest: Pointer; Size: Integer);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  for Index := 0 to Size - 1 do
    Move(Pointer(LongInt(Source) + Index)^,
        Pointer(LongInt(Dest) + (Size - Index - 1))^ , 1);
end;
function GetBytes(sg:single):Tbytes;
begin
   result:=??????
end;

function ReadSingle(sg:single):single;
var dest,temp:Tbytes;
begin
 temp := GetBytes(sg); //How todo ???
 ReverseBytes(temp,dest,length(temp));
 result:=dest;
end;
```

Comment: try going here - http://lingua.codegear.com/babelcode/

Comment: @MethodMan Thank you, but I get an error when acessing this site. Maybe my Internet provider?

Comment: `ReverseBytes(@sg,@Result,SizeOf(Single));` is all you need.

Comment: See also [How to convert Big Endian and how to flip the highest bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2882606/576719).

Comment: @LURD, shouldn't that be the answer?

Comment: I don't know when ReverseBytes was written, but it looks pretty suspicious. I does not work in 64 bit and it uses Move for every single byte? Really? These days, it should be replaced by code using PByte.

Comment: FWIW, for Single and Double, there are the functions htonf and htonl respectively. They convert Single and Double from network byte order to local byte order.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, you mean `Pointer(LongInt(` should be `Pointer(NativeUInt(`?

Comment: Yes, that too, but I would not call Move (with quite some overhead) for each byte, I would cast to PByte (or PAnsiChar) and assign each byte directly.

Comment: I cannot believe that I could have been responsible for that function. You are taking my name in vain! ;-)

Comment: Code appears to come from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966182/delphi-reverse-order-of-bytes

Comment: @David Hefferman One million of excuses. I had this code in my uinit and I had tagged as yours. But, it doesn´t . Sorry, Sorry, Sorry.

Comment: Don't worry. It made me laugh. I don't much care for the use of Move there or the bogus cast, as so many others have said. LURD's versions is solid. But I prefer Rudy's approach. The point is that you are not, semantically, reversing bytes. Semantically you are converting from network to host byte order. I personally regard that as an important distinction.

Comment: I removed the edit text. Thanks for the sentiment, but it's no problem at all. And the question is better off without it in my view. Don't worry, it's all good!

Comment: @David Hefferman 
thank you for your understanding. I have to agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to convert single float in big endian representation into a little endian.

This function will do that for you:

```
function ReadSingle(sg:single):single;
begin
  ReverseBytes(@sg,@Result,SizeOf(Single));
end;
```

Modern Delphi versions with [TSingleHelper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TSingleHelper) can reverse the bytes like this:

```
function ReadSingle(sg:Single):single;
begin
  Result.Bytes[0] := sg.Bytes[3];
  Result.Bytes[1] := sg.Bytes[2];
  Result.Bytes[2] := sg.Bytes[1];
  Result.Bytes[3] := sg.Bytes[0];
end;
```

---

**Note:** Floating point arguments is passed in the fpu register. Loading a defect float into the fpu register can trigger exceptions. I'd rather avoid treating the incoming data as floats until the byte order is corrected.

One example:

```
function ReadSingle(sg:PSingle): Single;
begin
  ReverseBytes(sg,@Result,SizeOf(Single));
end;
```

---

As @Rudy pointed out, the `ReverseBytes` function is not correct for the 64-bit compiler. The `LongInt()` casts must be replaced with `NativeUInt()` in both places. Then it works for both the 32-bit compilers and the 64-bit. And there are system functions to use as well, [ntohl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740069(v=vs.85).aspx) in the `winsock` library.

---

Here is another `ReverseBytes` alternative from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12969282/576719):

```
procedure ReverseBytes(Source, Dest: Pointer; Size: Integer);
begin
  Dest := PByte( NativeUInt(Dest) + Size - 1);
  while (Size > 0) do 
  begin
    PByte(Dest)^ := PByte(Source)^;
    Inc(PByte(Source));
    Dec(PByte(Dest));
    Dec(Size);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, but how do you know I have big endian representation?

Comment: Can I do the same to double type, just changing single to double ?

Comment: Big Endian, also known as network byte order, is a common format in motorola cpu's and also the byte order in which data is transferred in many protocols. It could also be a storage convention in data files. Windows computers are little endian, and I'm guessing that this is the representation you want. (It could be the other way around though).

Comment: You can use the same technique for doubles as well, yes.

Comment: Ok I will use it in dicom comunications. I guess you are sure. Thank you.

Comment: Is my ReveseBytes function OK?

Comment: If you got it from David, it's ok!

Comment: I don't find it OK. It doesn't work in Win64 and it uses Move for each byte. I would use `for I := 0 to Size - 1 do PByte(Dest)[I] := PByte(Source)[Size - I - 1];` and get rid of Move and the suspicious `Pointer(Longint(Pointer))`casts.

Comment: `htonl` is for 32 bit values, not for 64 bit values like doubles. `htonf` is in fact the same, just that it returns a float and not a u_long.

Comment: I did not write that code! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966182/delphi-reverse-order-of-bytes

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I could not find that when looking yesterday! Funny that your link took me to an answer of mine. If will copy that code here as well.

Comment: @David Heffernan Sorry for the damage caused. I edited my question.On million of excuses again. This was not my intention. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

For the conversion of network byte order to host byte order (in the case of Delphi, from big endian to little endian), you can use the functions `ntohl` and `ntohs` from `WinSock` or `WinSock2`:

```
uses
  WinSock2;

type
  PUInt32 = ^UInt32;
  PUInt64 = ^UInt64; 

function ReadSingle(sg: Single): Single;
begin
  Result := ntohl(PUInt32(@sg));
end;

function ReadDouble(db: Double): Double;
begin
  Result := UInt64(ntohl(PUInt64(@db) shr 32)) or
            UInt64(ntohl(PUInt32(@db))) shl 32;
end;
```

or, if you want to use ReverseBytes, then update it to modern times:

```
function ReverseBytes(Source, Dest: Pointer; Size: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Size - 1 do
    PByte(Dest)[I] := PByte(Source)[Size - I - 1];
end;

function ReadSingle(sg: Single): Single;
begin
  ReverseBytes(@sg, @Result, SizeOf(Single));
end;

function ReadDouble(db: Double): Double;
begin
  ReverseBytes(@db, @Result, Sizeof(Double));
end;
```

If you have an older version of Delphi that does not allow the `PByte`-as-array syntax, you can use `PAnsiChar` instead of `PByte`, but *shshshsh!*, that is a hack, so don't tell others I said that.

Comment: Only to complement it. In C#, I have public override long ReadInt64()
  {
   return IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder( someInt64);
  }. Can I substitute it in  Delphi with function ReadInt64():int64;
begin
        result:=Gstack.NetworkToHost(someInt64);
end;  without problems.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. You should try it and see if it produces the expected result, but it looks good.